# JQuery Autocomplete - simple masterpage issue

Tags: javascript, c#, autocomplete

[Jquery Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944285/best-pratice-to-send-asp-net-webform-to-jquery-autocomplete)

I simulated the above sample for an auto-complete text field. Works great until I incorporate a Master page. All of my other js works fine and I have a ScriptManager in the Master. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to dynamically reference both ids:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var emails = $("#<%=EmailList.ClientID%>").val();
        var emailList = emails.split(",");

        $("#<%=txtEmailAddress.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
            source: emailList
        });
    });
</script>
```